# membership provider - Syntax error in update statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Can you please tell me where is the error in the following update statement:

```
OleDbCommand updateCmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [" + tableName + "]" +
                " SET Password = ?, LastPasswordChangedDate = ?" +
                " WHERE Username = ? AND ApplicationName = ? AND IsLockedOut = False", conn);
```

the error is

[OleDbException (0x80040e14): Syntax error in UPDATE statement.]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word PASSWORD is a [reserved keyword](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx) for MS-Access Jet SQL.
If you want to use it in your tables then you need to encapsulate it with square brackets

```
OleDbCommand updateCmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [" + tableName + "]" +
            " SET [Password] = ?, LastPasswordChangedDate = ?" +
            " WHERE Username = ? AND ApplicationName = ? AND IsLockedOut = False", conn);
```

Comment: Yes that was the answer

Comment: @F.sh - If you are happy with the answer could you mark it so (click the 'tick')